# Returning integer and string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function as follow. I need to return two parameters. First the index that is as `list` and it is done by the function. The other parameter that I need to return is a string `str`.
What would be your best suggestion for these outputs? a list with two different parameters? or what? Please let me know your ideas! Thanks

```
public List<int> index_selexted(TreeNodeCollection treeView, List<int> list)
{
    List<int, List<string>> output_typ = new List<int, >();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView)
    {
        if (node.Checked)
        {
            list.Add(node.Index);
            string str = Regex.Match(node.Text, @" \((.*?)\) ").Groups[1].Value;            
        }
        else
        {
            index_selexted(node.Nodes, list);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean. Could you try to clarify your question? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem, with sample input and output, would really help. Note that it doesn't look like this is inherently WinForms specific - you happen to be using a `TreeNodeCollection`, but any tree type would presumably allow you to show the same problem.

Comment: Did you consider using parameters with `out` keyword? They could help you getting two (and more) "returns" from a function.

Comment: `List<int, List<string>> output_typ = new List<int, >();` won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `TreeNode.Index` is not *unique* within the entire `TreeNodeCollection` then `Dictionary<int, String>` is not a choice, but `Dictionary<int, List<String>>` will do

```
//TODO: find a better name for dict
public Dictionary<int, List<String>> index_selexted(
  TreeNodeCollection treeView, 
  Dictionary<int, List<String>> dict == null) { // == null for autocreation

  if (null == treeView)  
    throw new ArgumentNullException("treeView");

  if (null == dict)
    dict = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>();

  foreach (TreeNode node in treeView) 
    if (node.Checked) {
      String match = Regex.Match(node.Text, @" \((.*?)\) ").Groups[1].Value; 

      List<String> list;

      if (dict.TryGetValue(node.Index, out list))  
        list.Add(match);
      else
        dict.Add(node.Index, new List<String>() {match}); 
    }
    else 
      index_selexted(node.Nodes, dict);

  return dict;
}
```

And so you'll have something like this as an output: *index + all matches for it*:

```
  {1, ["abc", "def", "gh"]}
  {3, ["xyz"]}
```

I've added `dict == null` in order to make the call easier:

```
  // You don't have to pre-create the dictionary
  var myDict = index_selexted(myTreeView.Nodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var res = new Tuple<string, List<string>>("string1", new List<string>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But please notice that one output is integer and other is string.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do

```
public class IndexSelectionResult{
    public List<something> Index{get;set;}  
    public String StringResult 
}
```

and return an instance of that, OR, if you're lazy, you can return a TUPLE:

```
public Tuple<List<string>, string>> myFunction(){ /* code */}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
    public static List<int> index_selexted(TreeNodeCollection treeView, out string str)
    {
        str = null;

        var list = new List<int>();
        var output_typ = new List<int>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView)
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                list.Add(node.Index);
                str = Regex.Match(node.Text, @" \((.*?)\) ").Groups[1].Value;            
            }
            else
            {
                index_selexted(node.Nodes, list);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

usage as such:

```
var treeview = sometreeview;
string output;
var result = index_selected(treeview, out output);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

instead of using the list in your example (List> output_typ = new List();) consider

using a dictionary:

```
var output_typ = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

or a list of tuples:

```
var output_typ = new List<Tuple<int, List<string>>();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this in fact, it depends on your specific use case which one you'd prefer.

**Using a class**

```
class MyResult {
    public List<int> MyList { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

public MyResult index_selected(arg1..., arg2...) {
   return new MyResult {
      MyList = outputList,
      MyString = "outputString"
   }
}
```

Using a class is my preferred way. Though it may clutter if you have many return types it is by far the most readable solution.

**Using a tuple**

```
public Tuple<List<int>, string> index_selected(arg1..., arg2...) {
   return Tuple.Create(outputList, "outputString");
}
```

My second goto option is a tuple. It is a lot more difficult to determine what the values contained in the tuple represent. But doesn't require creating more classes and is a quick solution (I use it mostly for private methods where readability is not much of a concern).

**Using the out keyword**

```
public List<int> index_selected(arg1..., out string resultString) {
   resultString = null;
   /* Doing calculations and such */
   resultString = "
   return outputList;
}
```

In this case the string passed to the resultString parameter will be replaced by whatever you assign to it in the method (see [out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)). Depending on your use case you may also want to look at the [ref keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

This approach is rather error prone and is generally not preffered.